# Swift float multiplication error

Tags: swift, floating-point, operators, multiplication

This code fails:

```
let element: Float = self.getElement(row: 1, column: j)
let multiplier = powf(-1, j+2)*element
```

with this error:

> Playground execution failed: :140:51: error: cannot invoke '*' with an argument list of type '(Float, Float)'
>                       let multiplier = powf(-1, j+2)*element

Bear in mind that this occurs in this block:

```
for j in 0...self.columnCount {
```

where `columnCount` is a Float. Also, the first line does execute and so the `getElement` method indeed returns a Float.

I am completely puzzled by this as I see no reason why it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no implicit numeric conversion in swift, so you have to do explicit conversion when dealing with different types and/or when the expected type is different than the result of the expression.

In your case, `j` is an `Int` whereas `powf` expects a `Float`, so it must be converted as follows:

```
let multiplier = powf(-1, Float(j)+2)*element
```

Note that the `2` literal, although usually considered an integer, is automatically inferred a `Float` type by the compiler, so in that case an explicit conversion is not required.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by using `Float(j)` instead of `j` when calling `powf()`. Evidently, `j` cannot be implicitly converted to a Float.